# GraphQl API with Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, graphql

How can I integrate a GraphQL API into my Flutter app? I am relatively new to Flutter and have not worked with GraphQL before. Any guidance or resources on how to get started with integrating a GraphQL API into a Flutter app would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout a few libraries

1. https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter
2. https://pub.dev/packages/graphql

You can use this GraphQl Client

Some resources

1. https://blog.codemagic.io/flutter-graphql/
2. https://medium.flutterdevs.com/implement-graphql-with-flutter-153f30881915